# Prevent breakline in textarea

Tags: html, css, flask, textarea

I am sending a sentance from a textarea in my Postgresql DB, I need to read this sentance in an other page.

If the user's input contains a breakline :

> Hello
>
> everybody

my string will contains "\n", not a problem, but when I need to render it those elements are still here and the sentances looks like :

> Hello \n everybody

How can I prevent this?

I already tried to add CSS elements `white-space: pre-line;` and `white-space: pre-wrap;` and nothing changes

I also tried to change the string in my back/python with : `message.replace("\n","<br/>")` it failed too.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: If you literally get `\n` on your screen, something is translating linebreaks to the text `"\n"`. Look for where that happens, rather than trying to repair the damage afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`message.replace("\n", "<br/>")` should work, but you need to use the `|safe` filter in the template:

{{ message|safe }}

to keep the `<br>`s from printing as text.

This too:

`{{ msg|replace('\n','<br>')|safe }}`